# Are questions about UI in languages other than English on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

Are questions about User Interface messages or menu items involving languages other than English on-topic ?

Also, are questions about problems with translating/converting a UI from English to other languages on-topic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all of the above is on topic.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but since the audience is primarily English (and generally expected to be able to use English) the question itself should be in English, and it's most helpful that any non-English text in screenshots/etc is translated/explained unless it doesn't get in the way of answering questions.

As for translating an interface, that's what the [language](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), [localization](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) and [internationalization](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) tags are for where appropriate!